# Java encryption : which method can get me a result message without strange characters?

Tags: java, encryption

I want to put an encrypted license list on the web, so that valid users can use my app to get that list and check to see if their license Ids are on the list, so the apps can be activated. I've noticed some methods generate encrypted strings like this "M°+{Î..." with lots of strange characters in it, I wonder which method can generated regular characters that look this "dhjfjhf1232784dfjk" ?

Frank

Comment: Why a list? Would that not be exposing other peoples' license ids, the number of users, and stuff like that? Should not there be one file per user instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One typical mechanism used to get ASCII text from binary data is to [Base64-encode](http://www.wikihow.com/Encode-a-String-to-Base64-With-Java) it.

Comment: Note that is a separate step from encryption. **Encrypt** to an sequence of bytes. **Encode** that output to nice printable ASCII characters.