# BouncyCastle weird characters in signed String

Tags: java, openssl, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm trying to sign a string using BouncyCastle library. 
My code works, but the resulting string is full of weird characters and my instinct says something is wrong about it.
My code looks like this

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("certs/private.pem"));
PEMReader r = new PEMReader(fileReader);
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) r.readObject();
r.close()
String toSign = "hello world";
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA","BC");
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(toSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] signedArray = signature.sign();
String signedString = new String(signedArray, "UTF-8");
```

And the resulting string (signedString) looks (awfully) like this:

> �����jc.������c�1�#�ٶ����E8����a��f8���t�~W�{%��\Z#��it��ҽ;�n��k�n{U>&�d�_���&�?�N��g�
>   z\�k�g���e~�S4��ƎG�g��U�:��s>i�%YL�n3�����Y��9����T���}�Usb���&�����eշѾUr�Y�ڝ[j�h~mu\3U��j���c�U�ac����t��No-��1J�B]�

The private.pem was generated with this command

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3652 -nodes -out private.crt -keyout private.pem.
```

Any help or hint will be very appreciated.

**SOLVED**

What I did was to encode de byte array to Base64 using this line

```
byte[] encodedArray = org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.encode(signedArray);
```

and voalá!

Comment: This is perfectly fine. Perhaps you want to encode the byte array before printing.

Comment: You mean, something different than: new String(signedArray, "UTF-8") ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java encryption : which method can get me a result message without strange characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451747/java-encryption-which-method-can-get-me-a-result-message-without-strange-chara)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signature is a `byte[]`, it is not a string.  Attempting to treat a byte array as a string gives you what you have found.  Either retain and store the signature as a byte array, or else convert the byte array to a string-compatible format, such as Base64.  Java 8 contains the `Base64` class which will do the conversion for you.  If you do use Base64, then remember to convert back to bytes before checking the signature.